# How to generate JsObject in Node.js c++ addon as fast as in pure js?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8

I am new as a Node.js cpp-addon developer, I need to return a very big Object from cpp(Node.js cpp-addon) to Javascript logic, but I found that it is very slow to generate JsObject in C++ addon rather than pure js.
Here is my code and running result:

**cpp-addon case:**

```
var addon = require('bindings')('addon.node')

console.time('perf');
console.log('This should be result:', addon.getBigObject('foo bar'));
console.timeEnd('perf');
```

```
#include <napi.h>

Napi::Value GetBigObject(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) {
  Napi::Env m_env = info.Env();

  Napi::Object node = Napi::Object::New(m_env);
  node.Set(Napi::String::New(m_env, "foo"), Napi::Number::New(m_env, 1));
  node.Set(Napi::String::New(m_env, "body"), Napi::Array::New(m_env));


  for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
    Napi::Object stmt = Napi::Object::New(m_env);
    stmt.Set(Napi::String::New(m_env, "foo"), Napi::Number::New(m_env, 1));
    Napi::Array body = node.Get("body").As<Napi::Array>();
    auto len = std::to_string(body.Length());
    body.Set(Napi::String::New(m_env, len), stmt);
  }


  return node;
}

Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
  exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "getBigObject"), Napi::Function::New(env, GetBigObject));
  return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(addon, Init)
```

Running this code time cost:

```
perf: 2.782s
```

**pure-js case:**

```
var addon = require('./addon.js');

console.time('perf');
console.log('This should be result:', addon.getBigObject('var foo = 1;'));
console.timeEnd('perf');
```

```
module.exports.getBigObject = function() {
  const node = {};
  node.foo = 1;
  node.body = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
    let body = node.body;
    body.push({
      foo: 1
    });
  }
  return node;
}
```

Running this code time cost:

```
perf: 220.973ms
```

Why is this so slow that generate JsObject in cpp-addon? Perhaps it is relative to V8 Hidden-Class?
How could I generate JsObject in cpp-addon faster?

Answer (score 2):

(V8 developer here.)

> Why is this so slow that generate JsObject in cpp-addon?

In short: because in JavaScript, you benefit from engine optimizations; whereas in C++, you have to optimize things yourself.

> How could I generate JsObject in cpp-addon faster?

The general answer to "how can I make *anything* faster?" is: **profile it** to see where exactly the time is spent, and then see if you can avoid or optimize that.

Based on your code, I can make a few guesses at things that may be worth trying:

> `for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {`

That is a huge iteration count; creating so many handles (in the loop body) in a single `HandleScope` is probably contributing to the slowness. I'd use a nested loop to create a new HandleScope in the outer loop for every 1000 or so iterations of the inner loop. See [here](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html#n_api_making_handle_lifespan_shorter_than_that_of_the_native_method).

> `Napi::Object stmt = Napi::Object::New(m_env);` 
>   `stmt.Set(Napi::String::New(m_env, "foo"), Napi::Number::New(m_env, 1));`

The [V8 API](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/include/v8-template.h) has the `ObjectTemplate` system to churn out fresh copies of similar-looking objects as quickly as possible. It looks like N-API doesn't expose that though; so you could either move from N-API to using the V8 API directly, or simply live without it, hoping that it wouldn't make *too* much of a difference.

> `Napi::Array body = node.Get("body").As<Napi::Array>();`

Reading the `"body"` property of `node` in every iteration is unnecessary, as you know that it'll return the array you allocated previously, so just cache that in a local variable.

> `auto len = std::to_string(body.Length());`

Reading the length in every iteration is unnecessary, as it's always identical to `i`.

> `body.Set(Napi::String::New(m_env, len), stmt);`

Creating a string for an array index just to force the engine to convert that string back to a number is quite inefficient. `napi_set_element` avoids the unnecessary back-and-forth.

Another thing that the V8 API lets you do (but I can't find it on the N-API documentation) is compiling and executing any JS code you want. So if you really want the exact equivalent of the JS snippet, you can just call that JS snippet. (To save recompilation effort, I'd compile it as a separate step and cache the resulting function if you intend to call it repeatedly.)

Comment: After doing some testing, I can say Body.length() is just a little time cost, in my case (20000000s for loop) just cost  <0.1s. It is not the main slowness...

Comment: Makes sense; it's not surprising that that's the least impactful of the four concrete ideas I mentioned. Still, if you're aiming for ~200ms execution time, then saving ~100ms is absolutely worth it -- if you did that step last, it would appear much more important.

Comment: About the `handleScope` and `ObjectTemplate` you have mentioned, it does help me a lot! Thank you so much!  Just wanna ask you again, why is this so fast that using a nested loop to create a new HandleScope in the outer loop for every 1000 iteration? Is this way about the V8-Scavenger GC?

Comment: Not specifically the scavenger, but the GC in general, yes. Any time a major or minor GC cycle runs it has to iterate all handles in all active HandleScopes (which is a HandleScope's sole purpose). Whenever you create a `v8::Local`, that creates such a handle entry in the current HandleScope, and that entry will stay alive as long as the HandleScope does.

Comment: About the last thing you mentioned that compile and execute any JS code by V8 API, do you know how to do this in NAN addon? I have tried all the ways you said, in NAN addon I still get 600+ms cost while pure JS get just 200+ms. >.<

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html#n_api_napi_run_script sounds promising. (I don't know the N-API, I can only look at its documentation, and so can you!)